Springboot working in a microservice web application
I work in a microservice based web-application and I am still learning Springboot and Angular, my question is related to working of springboot, we have different tenants and environment, like stagging, sandbox and prod.
My understanding of Spring's application context in a high level is, when the application startups, the spring framework creates an IoC container that has all the beans in it, I work in one of the microservice for the cloud app, in local i understand that when i build and run my app in Intellij, the localhost starts and application context is built, that means beans are initialized for the classes that are annotated with @Component( this is one case ), now what i am having trouble in understanding is when the application context is built in stagging, sandbox or any other environment?
suppose to access the web app- link is www.ns-stagging.cloud.com, this would show the complete homescreen of the app, and in the ui we can navigate to different modules ( like order, lead etc)
each module has its own microservice.
Can someone please help me understanding the basic flow of how this microservice works and how springboot comes into picture for different environments.
I tried chatgpt, didnot understood from it.

Each environment will bring up the entire application. Unless you have profile specific beans with the "@Profile" annotation and different spring profiles running per environment.

For each environment, you should have different "instances" of your application (different deployments if you use Kubernetes, or different groups of VMs, depending on how your app is deployed).
Each app instance should be accessible through a dedicated endpoint: stage.my-app.com, dev.my-app.com, etc.
This way, your spring context is fully isolated between different environments, so you don't have to worry about the way it's built for a particular environment.
In Spring, there is a nice way of managing the configurations for each environment, through Spring Profiles: to define configs for dev, you just create a properties file called application-dev.properties and add dev-related configs there, same for stage and prod.
To turn on a profile, you just need to add the following param when running your app java -jar app.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev, and Spring will use the application-dev.properties config file.
If you pass --spring.profiles.active=stage, it will use the application-stage.properties file, and so on.
